# Recreating complete table from partial

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting really lost turning around a problem I'm having for quite some time.

My table looks like that

```
object No value  
1      0  foo 1  
1      3  foo 2  
1      4  foo 3  
1      8  foo 4  
2      0  faa 1  
2      8  faa 2
```

And I'd like t be able to rebuild the table like :

```
object No value OldNo  
1      0  foo 1 0  
1      1  foo 1 0  
1      2  foo 1 0  
1      3  foo 2 3  
1      4  foo 3 3  
1      5  foo 3 3  
1      6  foo 3 3  
1      7  foo 3 3  
1      8  foo 4 4  
2      0  faa 1 1  
2      1  faa 1 1  
2      2  faa 1 1  
2      3  faa 1 1  
2      4  faa 1 1  
2      5  faa 1 1  
2      6  faa 1 1  
2      7  faa 1 1  
2      8  faa 2 2
```

My table is filled by a program, that means I could always force the program to put data for each line, but I thought it would be a cleaner way to insert line only when needed.

My questions : 
- does someone know how to create view 2 from table 1 ?
- Is my way of doing things better or worse in terms of process cost ?

Thank you for any help .

Bart

Comment: Can you explain the logic for producing table2?

Comment: My first table is created by a program. 

I have users (represented here by field object), who are asked a certain number of times (field No) to modify a field (value). My program inserts a new row only when the value changed, which means if I have a value for event 1, 5, and 8, I know that the value hasn't changd between events 1 and 4, changed on 5, stayed the same from 5 to 7, changed on 8.

As I said, I could easily create the whole table (meaning creating a row each time, even if the value hasn't changed), but it looked to me lije duplicate rows.

Comment: What I need now is to be able to create a view with a line for each event, wich means if there is an line for event 4, get this line, if not get previous event...

I don't know if I made myself clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean something like this...??

SELECT DISTINCT 1 0 foo 1

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(obj INT NOT NULL
,seq INT NOT NULL
,val VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(obj,seq)
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES
(1 ,0 ,'foo 1'), 
(1 ,3 ,'foo 2'),
(1 ,4 ,'foo 3'),
(1 ,8 ,'foo 4'),
(2 ,0 ,'faa 1'),
(2 ,8 ,'faa 2'); 

CREATE TABLE ints(i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

SELECT obj
     , i
     , val
     , seq 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM ints 
        WHERE i BETWEEN 0 AND 8
     ) a 
     , my_table 
 ORDER 
    BY obj,seq,i;
+-----+---+-------+-----+
| obj | i | val   | seq |
+-----+---+-------+-----+
|   1 | 0 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 1 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 2 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 3 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 4 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 5 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 6 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 7 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 8 | foo 1 |   0 |
|   1 | 0 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 1 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 2 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 3 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 4 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 5 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 6 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 7 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 8 | foo 2 |   3 |
|   1 | 0 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 1 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 2 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 3 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 4 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 5 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 6 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 7 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 8 | foo 3 |   4 |
|   1 | 0 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 1 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 2 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 3 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 4 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 5 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 6 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 7 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   1 | 8 | foo 4 |   8 |
|   2 | 0 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 1 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 2 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 3 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 4 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 5 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 6 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 7 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 8 | faa 1 |   0 |
|   2 | 0 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 1 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 2 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 3 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 4 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 5 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 6 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 7 | faa 2 |   8 |
|   2 | 8 | faa 2 |   8 |
+-----+---+-------+-----+
54 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not bad at all !! I think I can try to work with tour example :)
I just need to limit the values => for example foo 3 must appear only between events 4 and 7.  
Also, I don't needto create a table, but rather work as a simple query, but I think we're getting somewhere !